# Mean Stack - angular app only runs on port 8100

Tags: angularjs, node.js, port, mean-stack

I have a mean app made in `angularjs` and `nodejs` . The app runs fine on local, both the frontend and backend are running on different ports. But on production, my frontend only runs on port `8100` . Although my node app is running fine on the port specified.

**Project directory**

My directory structure is like this on production as well as on local

```
--app
     | ---assets
       ---bower_components
       ---directives
       ---home
       ---misc
       ---product
       ---services
       ---user
       ---index.html
--backend
         | ---img
           ---models
           ---node_modules
           ---public
           ---routes
           ---app.js
           ---package.json

 --package.json (frontend)
```

**package jso frontend**

```
    {
    "name": "secret-project",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Secret Project",
    "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "bower": "^1.7.7",
        "http-server": "^0.9.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
        "karma": "^0.13.22",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.1",
        "protractor": "^4.0.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "bower install",
        "update-deps": "npm update",
        "postupdate-deps": "bower update",
        "prestart": "npm install",
        "start": "http-server -a x.x.x -p 8100 -c-1 ./app",
        "pretest": "npm install",
        "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
        "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
        "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
        "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
        "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
        "update-index-async": "node -e \"var fs=require('fs'),indexFile='app/index-async.html',loaderFile='app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js',loaderText=fs.readFileSync(loaderFile,'utf-8').split(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/).join('sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map'),indexText=fs.readFileSync(indexFile,'utf-8').split(/\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/).join('//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n'+loaderText+'    //@@NG_LOADER_END@@');fs.writeFileSync(indexFile,indexText);\""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ngcli-task-runner": "^1.0.3"
    }
}
```

**My app.js (node)**

```
 // importing modules
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

//path is a core module its already installed
var path = require('path');

//Use express methoods 

//express 
var app = express();

//port no
const port = 3000;

//getting routes defined in route js 
const route = require('./routes/route');

//connect to mongo db300
mongoose.connect('mongodb://121.658.153:27017/bit-manage-backend', {
    useMongoClient: true
});

//on connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('------------------------------------');
    console.log('connected to db');
    console.log('------------------------------------');
});


mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('------------------------------------');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('------------------------------------');
    }
});


//cors 
app.use(cors());

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
}



//body-parser -  parse all our json data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//calling api , all the routes starting with api are directed to route file
app.use('/api', route);

app.use(allowCrossDomain);


//bind server with port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('------------------------------------');
    console.log('server is running' +
        port);
    console.log('------------------------------------');
})
```

Now if i specifiy any other port other than 8100 in package.json it does not work. Whats the mistake I am doing ? I want to run it on port 80 which is default one. So when I remove the port from the line `"start": "http-server -a x.x.x -c-1 ./app",` . It still does not work.

**Note**
 I am doing this on production server not on local server.

Comment: how are you starting the front end? The backend is fine.

Comment: i just hit the ip address with the port mentioned in package json

Comment: since on changing the port in package.json is not reflected in your default case, are you sure that the port it takes to start the front end is coming from the package.json file?

Comment: yea man if i remove 8100 from package.json it doest not work

Comment: have you tried specifying like npm start --port 80

Comment: okay here is what is happening, if i change port and run npm start it works on the specified port. But once i do ctrl+c it stopped the process and obviously it stopped the website. Now how can I make sure that it keeps running. I mean i dont have to do it everytime. Or may be there is another way ?